# How to obtain the container class of an Actionsheet?

Tags: iphone

I am a green hand of iPhone development, and I just get confused about a method UIActionsheet，which is the "showInView". So what is the relation between the view who called the actionsheet and the actionsheet it self.
  Actually, I wannt to customize the button in an actionsheet, so I create a class for it and overide the methods, and I want really call the methods in the superview, anybody got a solution?

Thank you!
（btw， I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.）

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated

{........
   else if (buttonIndex==sharers.count+1)
    {

     AddCommentViewController *parentController=(AddCommentViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder];
}
```

Comment: I can not see anything in the code you show that is related to customizing an action sheets button, or making any subclass.

Comment: It is in the AddCommentViewController that I calld the customized Actionsheet. The code here is in the Actionsheet class, where I want to call the methods in the AddCommentViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API for accessing the container, or *owner* of a `UIActionSheet`.

You should not use the `superview` property to try to get to the owner, the internal view layout for the action sheet is private and can/will change between OS updates.

If you need to get hold of the owner then add a proper property to your `UIActionSheet` subclass to do this. For example:

```
@protocol MYActionSheetChoiceDelegate;

@interface MYActionSheet : UIActionSheet <UIActionSheetDelegate> {}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MYActionSheetChoiceDelegate> choiceDelegate; 

@end
```

Notice that I name the property `choiceDelegate` since the `delegate` property is already taken. Now assuming your subclass is also your it's own `UIActionSheetDelegate` this can be done:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)sheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{
    if (index == SOME_INDEX) {
       [self.choiceDelegate actionSheet:self didChooseSomething:index];
    }
}
```

Change and fill the gaps to your own needs.